# how to count grand total in row data bound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to make summation of total column as a grand total . how to count grand total and show in label in rowdatabound event ?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   CssClass="gridview"  DataKeyNames="Id"  Width="633px" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">


                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Unit Price" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            int value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
            int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
            int total = value * value2;
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = Convert.ToString(total);


    int GrandTotal = +total;
    lblgrandTotal = GrandTotal.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: `grand total` of what all the `totals`?

Comment: yes. i want to count all totals summation. i updated kindly see

Comment: Take `int GrandTotal` outside of `protected ` scope. make it a global variable not local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the existing `GridView1_RowDataBound` event by adding the total to the variable for each row like this:-

```
 int grandTotal = 0;
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
            int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
            int total = value * value2;
            grandTotal += total;
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = Convert.ToString(total);
            lblgrandTota.Text = grandTotal.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I have placed the `grandTotal` variable outside the event handler method so that it won't be initialized for each row.

Comment: label showing this this. Grand Total: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label  i think i can do it..

Comment: @krishnamohan - I guess there was a confusion between _grandTotal_ & your _GrandTotal_. Corrected.